# when creating table in hive in mac os failing with error localhost:9000 failed on connection

Tags: macos, hadoop, hive

hive> CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS inconv_seql;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.net.ConnectException Call From User-MacBook-Air.local/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

the above error is due to hadoop demons with the ports `9000` are not running in your local machine,

please start hadoop and then start hive by following the below steps.

**1. check hadoop is running,**

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ jps
```

if you could not find any hadoop daemons running in your local, then start hadoop follow the below command,

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh
```

**2. check the hive-site.xml,core-site.xml**
**hive-site.xml**

```
<property> 
<name>hive.metastore.db.type</name> 
<value>DERBY</value> 
<description> Expects one of [derby, oracle, mysql, mssql, postgres]. Type of database used by the metastore. Information schema &amp; JDBCStorageHandler depend on it. </description> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name> 
<value>hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse</value> 
<description>location of default database for the warehouse</description> </property>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration> 
<property> 
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
<value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value> 
<description>A base for other temporary directories</description> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>fs.default.name</name> 
<value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

and try to launch hive terminal and proceed.

Comment: sasanka@Sasankas-MacBook-Air ~ % jps
1248 NameNode
1489 SecondaryNameNode
1860 Jps
1686 ResourceManager
1352 DataNode
1787 NodeManager
hive> CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS inconv_seql;
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.net.ConnectException Call From Sasankas-MacBook-Air.local/192.168.0.5 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused)
Resource Manager: http://localhost:9870

Comment: all process are started and still i am facing error i am not using localhost:9000 for resource my resources are
Resource Manager: http://localhost:9870
JobTracker: http://localhost:8088/
Node Specific Info: http://localhost:8042/

Comment: what's your hadoop & hive version. can you update the `hive-site.xml`

Comment: <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.db.type</name>
    <value>DERBY</value>
    <description>
      Expects one of [derby, oracle, mysql, mssql, postgres].
      Type of database used by the metastore. Information schema &amp; JDBCStorageHandler depend on it.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000//user/hive/warehouse</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
  </property>

Comment: why you are referring to 9000??

Comment: your hdfs site.xml pls?

Comment: these are existing settings i didnt change what should be there please help me with that i have only changed pwd , connection properties and data nuclues

Comment: <configuration>
 <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>

Comment: can you share the output `netstat -tupln | grep 9000` & your `core-sit.xml`

Comment: <configuration>
<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
~

Comment: change your hive-site.xml as `<property> <name>hive.metastore.db.type</name> <value>DERBY</value> <description> Expects one of [derby, oracle, mysql, mssql, postgres]. Type of database used by the metastore. Information schema &amp; JDBCStorageHandler depend on it. </description> </property> <property> <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name> <value>hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/warehouse</value> <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description> </property>` and try to start hive

Comment: updated the answer, please upvote and accept the answer so that we can close the thread!